# Jquery mobile navigation - cant scroll down to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have the following problem. I've created my first mobile navigation for a responsive website, but after the menü switch to the mobile menu, i cant scroll down, after clicking on one of the hrefs.
In usually case by clicking on one of them, you scroll automatically down to the content, but if you are on a mobile device, my menu switch to the mobile navigation.

I've read, that the problem could caused by my jquery code "html()".
Maybe one of you guys had the same problem.

Thanks a lot

```
$("#nav_mobile").html($("#nav_main").html());
    $("#menu_button span").click(function(){
    if ($("#nav_mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
        $("#nav_mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    } else {
        $("#nav_mobile ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }
}); 



<div id="menu_button">
    <span>Menu</span>
</div>
<nav id="nav_main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1. Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2. Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3. Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4. Link</a></li> 
   </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="nav_mobile"></nav>
```

Comment: I really believe it would be better for you to repeat the ul of you nav_main in your nav_mobile, and to hide via CSS using breakpoint you need to display the nav_mobile whenever needed. Changing the HTML this way will break your event listeners...